# I am trying to take an input with a space in the postal code but for some reason my code is not working

Tags: c

```
    address.postalCode[8];
    address.city[41]='\0';
    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", address.postalCode);
    printf("\nPlease enter the contact's city: ");
    scanf("%s", address.city);
```

so here the I have declared two arrays type struct and I am trying to get an input in postal code including a space but the scanf is not being executed it aimply jumps and print to ask for the city

Comment: I suggest you also need the `%[^\n]` format spec for the city. Any input with a space ("White City") that would otherwise break at the first whitespace when using `%s` format spec.

Comment: yeah but for now i need to make my postal code thing work

Comment: 1) What should this accomplish: `address.postalCode[8];`? 2) Or this: `address.city[41]='\0';`? 3) When having trouble, or rather _always_ check the return value from `scanf()` (or from any function which returns a meaningful value); this can help determine if input is as expected. 4) Heed previous advice about `scanf()` format string, or consider forgetting that `scanf()` exists and learn about `fgets()`.

Comment: According to my assignment I am supposed to make it hold only 7 characters

Comment: Yup, it did. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Why do you have `s` after `%[^\n]`? Is the user supposed to put an `s` after the postal code?

Comment: Never mind, it was a mistake